# Python Selenium Automation not launching from Node

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

We have a python 2.7 based selenium automation that does an activity of launching IE page and does some maintenance work there. We used PyInstaller to make an .exe out of  the pyscript and we noticed that it works when executed on a command shell or via a bat file wrapper. If we put it in a single NodeJS code snippet and execute it, it works. Below is the piece of code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
/**
 * Function to execute exe
 * @param {string} fileName The name of the executable file to run.
 * @param {string[]} params List of string arguments.
 * @param {string} path Current working directory of the child process.
 */

function executePyScriptAutomationProcess(fileName, params, path) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(fileName, params, { cwd: path }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                console.log('Error Py Script automation:' + data);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
                console.log('Py auto Script logged data :' + data);
            }
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

const fileName = `C:\\tcnxbot_data\\automated_script\\auto.exe`;
console.log("fileName:" + fileName);
const params = ['ics0300pub.ics-eu-1.abcd.com', 'kjames'];
const path = `C:\\tcnxbot_data\\automated_script`;
executePyScriptAutomationProcess(fileName, params, path);
exports.executePyScriptAutomationProcess = executePyScriptAutomationProcess;
```

But if we try to include this in our Azure chatbot NodeJS code, then this automation is not getting triggered. We are instead getting an error of this sort.

```
const exec = require('./PyscriptExec');
                                const fileName = `C:\\tcnxbot_data\\automated_script\\auto.exe`;
                                const params = ['ics0300pub.ics-eu-1.abcd.com', 'kjames'];
                                const path = `C:\\tcnxbot_data\\automated_script`;
                                exec.executePyScriptAutomationProcess(fileName, params, path);
```

The error message that we get is shown below:

```
Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:2273/'
```

My question is this. This is not a normal exe. This exe launched an IE window as previously stated. Does that mean we are supposed to use a special call within NodeJS to do the task?. We tried `execFile`, `exec` methods so far but in vain. I also see that there are `fork` and `spawn` methods available. But not able to understand what we are missing.

Note that the above message when google shows that it is related to protected mode setting on browser. I have already done that. Infact as mentioned earlier, it works when run independently. But when we plugin the NodeJS back end it does not work anymore.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pavan.